Gsap on scroll animation with pin in reactjs
I'm trying to do the scroll pin animation in reactjs. There I'm using swiper and gsap. My requirement is when scroll to section it need to pin and then swiper needs to be slide, untill end.
I'm taking reference from below codepen.
Js version:
https://codepen.io/snorkltv/pen/QWzwmjJ
Im trying to replicate the codepen example in reactjs, I have tried, but Im strucked in rendering issue.
Here I have add the code on Stackbitz
Reactjs:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rpn1iq?file=src%2FApp.jsx
Can some please help me to fix the reactjs code....
